# Appengine Error Ignoring file too long

Tags: google-app-engine, upload, python-2.7, webapp2

I'm new in appengine, i'm trying to deploy my project but i have error:

ERROR appcfg.py:2189 Ignoring file 'odm2.txt': Too long (max 32000000 bytes, file is 56182913 bytes)

It is possible to upload this file without split?

Answer (score 1):

But you can upload it to [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-storage), and then access it from your app using either the [BlobReader](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobreaderclass) API or the [Files API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/functions?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

[According to Google](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp):

> A maximum size of files to upload, as a number of bytes. Files larger than this size will not be uploaded. The default is 10485760. The server currently enforces a maximum file size of 10,485,760 bytes, so increasing this value will not have any effect.

Interestingly, that page must be out of date if it's telling you that the max currently is 32000000 bytes. However, there doesn't seem to be any way to work around that.

What kind of file is odm2.txt? Is it something you're going to be storing in the datastore?

Depending on what you need to do with it, [you could upload it to the blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Uploading_a_Blob), within your app itself.